# How do I make Propel retain associative format with singular selects?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, select, propel

I have the following Criteria in Propel:

```
$q = \UserQuery::create();
$q->select(array('id', 'name'));
$q->orderBy('name');
$q->setOffset($offset);
$q->setLimit($limit);
return $q->find();
```

This works fine, and gives me a two-dimensional array with id and name keys in the inner array, i.e.

```
array( array("id" => 1, "name" => 'A'), array("id" => 2, "name" => 'B') )
```

However, if I run the following:

```
$q = \UserQuery::create();
$q->select(array('id'));
$q->orderBy('id');
$q->setOffset($offset);
$q->setLimit($limit);
return $q->find();
```

It gives me a one-dimensional array with no column keys, only indexes, i.e.

```
array(1, 2)
```

If I use the PropelArrayFormatter:

```
$q = \UserQuery::create();
$q->select(array('id'));
$q->orderBy('id');
$q->setOffset($offset);
$q->setLimit($limit);
$q->setFormatter('PropelArrayFormatter');
return $q->find();
```

It hydrates the entire object with null values:

```
array( array("id" => 1, "name" => null, "hash" => null, "last_login" => null), array("id" => 2, "name" => null, "hash" => null, "last_login" => null) )
```

If I add:

```
$q->setFormatter('PropelArrayFormatter');
```

Then I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in BaseUser.php on line 1518
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in BaseUser.php on line 1519
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in BaseUser.php on line 1520
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in BaseUser.php on line 1521
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in BaseUser.php on line 1522
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in BaseUser.php on line 1523
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in BaseUser.php on line 1524
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9 in BaseUser.php on line 1525
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 10 in BaseUser.php on line 1526
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 11 in BaseUser.php on line 1527
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 12 in BaseUser.php on line 1528
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 13 in BaseUser.php on line 1529
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 14 in BaseUser.php on line 1530
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 15 in BaseUser.php on line 1531
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 16 in BaseUser.php on line 1532
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 17 in BaseUser.php on line 1533
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 18 in BaseUser.php on line 1534
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 19 in BaseUser.php on line 1535
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 20 in BaseUser.php on line 1536
```

And nothing is returned. I have also tried PropelSimpleArrayFormatter, and it never returns an associative array:

```
$q->setFormatter('PropelSimpleArrayFormatter');
```

The result:

```
PropelArrayCollection::__set_state(array(
   0 => '123',
   1 => '126',
   2 => '133',
   3 => '242',
   4 => '256',
   5 => '272',
   6 => '283',
   7 => '284',
   8 => '474',
   9 => '617',
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Propel uses per default `SimpleArrayFormatter` if you limit the selected columns, which does some handy stuff as you've seen.

If you want to stick with the normal behavior, set the normal `ArrayFormatter` as Formatter:

```
$q->setFormatter('\Propel\Runtime\Formatter\ArrayFormatter');
```

Comment: This gave me `PHP Fatal error:  Class '\\Propel\\Runtime\\Formatter\\ArrayFormatter' not found in propel/query/ModelCriteria.php on line 171`.

Comment: Ah, I was talking about Propel2. In Propel1 its a different Formatter class. Try $q->setFormatter('PropelArrayFormatter');

Comment: The problem is that PropelArrayFormatter hydrates the entire object with null values where they cannot be found. Also causes a lot of `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset` messages.

Comment: I updated my question with the results of `PropelArrayFormatter` and `PropelSimpleArrayFormatter`.